# Failing installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on MacBookPro 17-inch early 2011

Tags: system-installation, macbook, macbook-pro

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBookPro 17 inch early 2011. I tried to run the install from a USB drive. The installation and also "try before installing" both stopped with 3 lines in the terminal

```
[    8.535620] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000e
[    8.535645] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    8.547627] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000e
```

I took out the disk from the 17-inch computer and put it in a Macbook Pro 13 inch also early 2011. And it worked. I managed to install Ubuntu, and afterwards select which OS to boot (Ubuntu or OS X).

However when putting the disk with the installed Ubuntu and OSX back into the 17" Macbook pro, and booting Ubuntu, it stops with a purple screen. 
I find it strange that two almost identical computers behave differently. Any suggestions?

Comment: The instructions here worked for me with 16.04 LTS. Might be worth a shot: https://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-2011-macbook-pro/